# Git show all branches (but not stashes) in log

Tags: git, git-log, git-stash

I have a Git alias that expands to:

```
git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate
```

According to `man git log` there are a couple of suspicious options: `--not` and `--branches`; but I can't make it work properly.

How should I edit that to hide the stashes?

---

**FYI**: as per the [accepted question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9438578/477168) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437182/git-show-all-branches-but-not-stashes-in-log#comment46034208_9438578) my `.gitconfig` alias now looks like this:

```
[alias]
    l = log --branches --remotes --tags --graph --oneline --decorate --notes HEAD
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Instead of doing `--all` and then trying to filter out the stashes, don't ever include them in the first place:

```
git log --branches --remotes --tags --graph --oneline --decorate
```

The main problem that arises from trying to filter them out afterwards is that if the stash is the latest commit on that branch (because even though it's not the `head` of the branch, it's still the most recent descendant of it), it can actually filter out the entire branch from the log, which isn't what you want.

Comment: I'd suspect `--tags` to be redundant, since no tag should ever be a descendant of the `head` of a branch or remote, though I haven't verified this.

Comment: Just tried this: `git checkout -b test`; added a commit ; `git tag foo` ; `git checkout master` ; `git branch -D test`. The tag is there but it will not be shown without `--tags`.

Comment: One small addition -- you should add `HEAD` to the end.  Otherwise, if you're in detached HEAD mode and no other ref points to the HEAD commit, you won't see it in the graph.

Answer (score 16):

My alias:

```
[alias]
    l = log --oneline --decorate --graph --exclude=refs/stash
```

In this case you will be able to use these forms without showing the stash:

- `git l` for the current branch
- `git l feature234` for a specific branch
- `git l --all` for the overall history

From the manual:

> --exclude=<glob pattern>
>
> Do not include refs matching  that the next --all, --branches, --tags, --remotes, or --glob would otherwise consider.

Comment: Note that the order of parameters matters: `--all --exclude=refs/stash` would still include the stash, while `--exclude=refs/stash --all` would correctly exclude it.

Answer (score 5):

Note that [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9438578/46058) wouldn't work for hiding [StGit](https://stacked-git.github.io/)<sup>1.)</sup> branches `<branch>.stgit` (from StGit version 0.15) which otherwise litter the output making it unusable.

Currently I use the following solution:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate \
  $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads/ refs/remotes/ |
    grep -v "\.stgit$")
```

---

*<sup>1.)</sup> StGit ("**St**acked **Git**") provides Quilt/mq--like functionality to Git (i.e. pushing/popping patches to/from a stack).*

Comment: Consider using `--exclude`. Like: `git log --graph --exclude=refs/heads/*.stgit --exclude=refs/patches/*  --exclude=refs/stash --all`