# How can I show the name of branches on every commit in `git log`

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log

In Gitk, showing a commit gives output like this:

```
Author: ...
Committer: ...
Parent: ...auth/parser)
Parent: ... (Merge branch '...')
Child:  ...
Branches: remotes/me/foo, foo
```

Is there a way to get this kind of output in `git log`? Using `git log --graph` gives similar information, but in my repository with long-lived branches, it can take a lot of scrolling to find which branch a commit was on.

(A similar question to [How can I show the name of branches in `git log`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841405/how-can-i-show-the-name-of-branches-in-git-log))

Answer (score 5):

I use this:

```
git log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad [%an] %s%d\" --graph --date=short
--all --date-order
```

I added alias to my global `.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    hist = log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad [%an] %s%d\" --graph --date=short --all --date-order
```

and can call simple `git hist`

It makes very pretty-to-read revisions tree with short commits hash, author, date, branches, HEADs etc on one line

Comment: I use something similar, but "%d" only gives labels the tip of each branch. I was hoping for something which would label every commit.

Comment: The one I use:   git log --pretty='%Cblue%h%C(cyan)%d%Cred %cn %Cgreen %ar %Creset %s'

Comment: @radisto, I tried your command. It gives an error: fatal: ambiguous argument '%ad': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'. I am using git version 1.9.3

Comment: looks like you use some additional log formatting, which ambiguous with '%ad'. see http://superuser.com/questions/273570/git-log-alias-fatal-ambiguous-argument-ad-unknown-revision-or-path

Comment: It doesn't show the branches on all commits, only on the last ones.