# Checking which file in two branches has a later commit

Tags: git

I want to (manually) merge changes in another branch into master.  `git diff --name-only` gives me only all the files that are different. I don't want to merge a file that has a later commit in master (which most of the time means the file wasn't changed in the other branch).

For a file, how do I show which branch has a later commit? Basically I want to show the output of `git log -1 somefile` in two branches? Is there a way to avoid running the `git log` command twice, once for each branch?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you intend to run `git merge` here, but if you do, you don't get to control which files get merged: merge picks three commits, and uses those three inputs to diff *all* the files from the merge base to each branch tip, which means this kind of inspection isn't really going to help. (But if you're going to merge manually, or run `git merge-file` on specific files, see VonC's answer and my comment.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the [`--all --branches` log parameters](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---all):

```
git log -1 --all --branches -- yourFile
```

That will give you the most recent commit across all branches.

To limit that to only two branches, the `--branches` takes a [shell glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).
But that does [not support an "or" in the pattern expression though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50220/7490). You might have [to display the branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1841429/6309) and grep for the ones you want.

As [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515394/checking-which-file-in-two-branches-has-a-later-commit/56516519?noredirect=1#comment99619512_56516519), a [revision range](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-ltrevisionrangegt) [branch1...branch2](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-Theem82308203emthree-dotSymmetricDifferenceNotation) is also a simpler alternative.
That would be using the [three dots notation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-Theem82308203emthree-dotSymmetricDifferenceNotation), to target the  set of commits that are reachable from either one of `branch1` (left side) or `branch2` (right side) but not from both.

So:

```
git log -1 branch1...branch2 -- yourFile
```

---

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), the notion of "revision range" is clarified:

See [commit f302c1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f302c1e4aa09ca6120968256d65dba291990929d) (18 May 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b009fd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b009fd41e8d66e6a1fb4e59f95ea48a18fc0194c), 10 Jun 2021)</sup>

> ### [`revisions(7)`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f302c1e4aa09ca6120968256d65dba291990929d): clarify that most commands take a single revision range

> Sometimes new people are confused by how a revision "range" works, in that it is not a random collection of commits but a set of commits that are all connected to each other, and most Git commands work on a single such "range".
>
> Give an example to clarify it.

`revisions` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f302c1e4aa09ca6120968256d65dba291990929d/Documentation/revisions.txt#L263-L265):

> There are several notations to specify a set of connected commits
> (called a "revision range"), illustrated below.

`revisions` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f302c1e4aa09ca6120968256d65dba291990929d/Documentation/revisions.txt#L300-L319):

> Commands that are specifically designed to take two distinct ranges
> (e.g. "`git range-diff R1 R2`" to compare two ranges) do exist, but
> they are exceptions.
>
> Unless otherwise noted, all "`git`" commands
> that operate on a set of commits work on a single revision range.
> In other words, writing two "two-dot range notation" next to each
> other, e.g.
>
> ```
> $ git log A..B C..D
> ```
>
> does *not* specify two revision ranges for most commands.  Instead
> it will name a single connected set of commits, i.e. those that are
> reachable from either B or D but are reachable from neither A or C.
> In a linear history like this:
>
> ---A---B---o---o---C---D
>
> because `A` and `B` are reachable from `C`, the revision range specified
> by these two dotted ranges is a single commit `D`.

Comment: `--all` includes `--branches`: it's basically equivalent to `--branches --tags --remotes` except that it also includes things like `refs/stash` too (all refs). So OP probably wants just `--branches`, or in this case, `git log -1 branch1 branch2 -- yourfile`.

Comment: @torek Did you meant `branch1...branch2`, as in https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-Theem82308203emthree-dotSymmetricDifferenceNotation, meaning: " the set of commits that are reachable from either one of `branch1` (left side) or `branch2` (right side) but not from both"?

Comment: No, the idea here was to look at commits, newest-first (`git log`'s default sorting order when it has two commits to look at is by highest-committer-date) until one of them meets the `-- yourFile` criterion, then show that one commit and quit. However, the three-dot notation would be even more useful if you want to show *nothing* if the file isn't changed since common starting commits. (or in other words, your improvement of my improvement is (I think) an improvement :-) )

Comment: @torek OK. Improvement FTW!

Comment: Thanks. I have a question about the output. I find that when the latest is in a branch other than master, the branch name is shown in color after the commit id. When the latest is in master, no branch name is indicated. It's the same whether I use `master...b2` or `b2...master`. Is this how it is supposed to work?

Comment: @OldGeezer `master...b2` or `rb2...master` will return indeed the same set of commits. To avoid the branch name in color being added, use the `---no-decorate` option